# asterisk Function MAILBOX_EXISTS not registered

Tags: centos, asterisk, freepbx

I am at a complete loss.  I have searched for a while now and I cannot get a mailbox to work.

CentOs 6.7
asterisk 1.8.32
freePBX

I did this installation through the wiki.freepbx
http://wiki.freepbx.org/display/FOP/Installing+FreePBX+12+on+CentOS+6.5
in voicemail admin it says my mailbox are 'unactivated'

in asterisk CLI when I try *97 softphone hangs up but CLI provides these errors

[2015-11-22 23:22:05] ERROR[10502]: pbx.c:4140 ast_func_read: Function MAILBOX_EXISTS not registered

[2015-11-22 23:22:05] WARNING[10502]: func_logic.c:192 acf_if: Syntax IF(?[][:])  (expr must be non-null, and either  or  must be non-null)

[2015-11-22 23:22:05] WARNING[10502]: func_logic.c:193 acf_if:       In this case, ='', ='SUCCESS', and ='FAILED'
    -- Executing [*97@from-internal:5] Set("SIP/711-000000f1", "VMBOXEXISTSSTATUS=") in new stack
    -- Executing [*97@from-internal:6] GotoIf("SIP/711-000000f1", "0?mbexist") in new stack

[2015-11-22 23:22:05] WARNING[10502]: pbx.c:4706 pbx_extension_helper: No application 'VoiceMailMain' for extension (from-internal, *97, 7)
  == Spawn extension (from-internal, *97, 7) exited non-zero on 'SIP/711-000000f1'
    -- Executing [h@from-internal:1] Hangup("SIP/711-000000f1", "") in new stack
  == Spawn extension (from-internal, h, 1) exited non-zero on 'SIP/711-000000f1'

[2015-11-22 23:22:06] WARNING[2803]: chan_sip.c:25562 handle_request_subscribe: SUBSCRIBE failure: unrecognized format:'application/watcherinfo+xml' pvt: subscribed: 0, stateid: -1, laststate: 0,dialogver: 0, subscribecont: '', subscribeuri: ''

I would appreciate any ideas

Answer (score 0):

The line **"Syntax IF(?[][:]) (ex"** suggests your dialplan was not properly constructed by FreePBX.  Either you have severely misconfigured (or under configured) FreePBX, or you have some form of corruption on your system.

Comment: thanks for the feedback.  Any Tshooting ideas?  I'd rather not go through a re-install...